# Adding image in the column of jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to display a small image in the first column of jqgrid for all data I get from DB.

```
jquery("#tableName").jqgrid({
.....
colNames : ['', ''],
colModel : [{
    width : '25%',
    },{
    name : 'someValue',
    index : 'somevalue',
    widht : '75%',
    sorttype: 'text'
}]
});
```

I want to add an image in the first colmodel. i tried formatter, but not sure about cellvalue, row object, options. Any help would be appreciated.

I did something like this for image

```
function imageFormat( cellvalue, options, rowObject ){
        return '<img src="'+cellvalue+'" />';
    }
```

Where should i give the image src ? how to mention the imageformat in the colmodel ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need add *different* images in different rows? Where you hold URL to the image? What you mean under "imageformat"?

Comment: I don't need different images. I just need a single image to be displayed in all the rows. I got this function from one of the pages. so just tried it out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need to set image in for example the first column of the grid you can define the grid

```js
$("#tableName").jqGrid({
    .....
    colNames: ['', ''],
    colModel: [
        {
            name: 'someUniqueColumnName',
            width: 25,
            fixed: true,
            formatter: function () {
                return "<img src='http://myserver/path/i.jpg' alt='my image' />";
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'someValue',
            width: 123 // width of column in pixel
        }
    ],
    ...
});
```

The `formatter` need just return a string which is HTML fragment which need be placed in the column. Because all parameters in JavaScript are optional and we need no then we can define `formatter` as function without parameters. The property `width` is the size of column in pixel. If you use other jqGrid options like `autowidth: true` or specify *the whole width* of the grid with respect of `width` option (and if you don't use `shrinkToFit: false` option)  then jqGrid will *scale* the column width based on the value of `width` property of the column in `colModel`. To have no scaling of the column with the image I included `fixed: true` property additionally.

Some common remark: you should be careful with case of names in JavaScript. For example the first line of code which you posted (`jquery("#tableName").jqgrid({`) should be replaced with  `jQuery("#tableName").jqGrid({`.

Comment: @Oleg, How do i image bind dynamic content for eg: collection of image in to the folder

Comment: @Sajith: [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter)   have assess to the full information for the row of data by the 3-d parameter (`rowObject`). It allows to extend the information returned from the server for every row with additional *dynamic* information, for example, URL of the image, tooltip (the value of `title` attribute) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the image through xml or json in your url parameter like this:

```
$image = "&lt;a href='#'>&lt;img src='folders/images/arrow.jpg' border='0' valign='middle' title='Edit something'>&lt;a>";



echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?$et\n"; 
echo "<rows>"; echo "<page>".$page."</page>"; 
echo "<total>".$total_pages."</total>"; 
echo "<records>".$count."</records>"; // be sure to put text data in CDATA 

    echo "<row id='". $id."'>"; 
    echo "<cell>". $image."</cell>"; 
    echo "</row>"; 
    } 
 echo "</rows>";
```

note that < is `&lt;`

Answer (score 0):

Look this example :)

```
$("#jsgrid").jsGrid({
autoload: true,
width: 350,
filtering: true,
inserting: true,
controller: {
    loadData: function(filter) {
        return !filter.Name 
            ? data
            : $.grep(data, function(item) { return item.Name.indexOf(filter.Name) > -1; });

        // use ajax request to load data from the server
        /*
        return $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/YourUrlToAddItemFilteringScript",
            data: filter
        });
        */
    },
    insertItem: function(insertingItem) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("Name", insertingItem.Name);
        formData.append("Img[]", insertingItem.Img, insertingItem.Img.name);

        return $.ajax({
            method: "post",
            type: "POST",
            url: "/YourUrlToAddItemAndSaveImage",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    }        
},
fields: [
    {
        name: "Img",
        itemTemplate: function(val, item) {
            return $("<img>").attr("src", val).css({ height: 50, width: 50 }).on("click", function() {
                $("#imagePreview").attr("src", item.Img);
                $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            });
        },
        insertTemplate: function() {
            var insertControl = this.insertControl = $("<input>").prop("type", "file");
            return insertControl;
        },
        insertValue: function() {
            return this.insertControl[0].files[0]; 
        },
        align: "center",
        width: 120
    },
    { type: "text", name: "Name" },
    { type: "control", editButton: false }
]});
```

You can see the complete example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/tabalinas/ccy9u7pa/16/